# Java Binary Search Tree with custom Object as element/node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree that contains an object with a string and an int:

```
    public Person() {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
    }
    public Person(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
```

I add all the Person objects into my tree but I'm unsure of how to grab the name string? I only know how to grab the whole object given that I give a specific object to search for but I want to be able to search for a given name. I'm only looking for how to grab the string name, not the implementation of the search.

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Have a **public getter** method for attribute name.

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private int age;
 //your cons
public String getName(){
   return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
 this.name = name;
}
}
```

When you get an person object from your tree. you could just call the getter method on its instance.

```
     Person p1 = getThePersonFromtheTree;
     System.out.println(p1.getName());
```

### EDIT:

> Is it possible to walk through the tree until it finds that name?

ofcourse, you just need to keep iterating over your tree untill you find an object with a specific name. for instance if you wanna find a person object with a name **krishna**.

```
    for(int i=0; i<personsTree.size(); i++){
          if(personsTree.getTheObj(i).getName().equals("Krishna")){
               //found the object with name krishna
           }
     }
```

Comment: Is it possible to walk through the tree until it finds that name? My tree seems to only be able to walk through the tree and find a specific object (meaning I have to input the object I want to find and not just the string name). I'm using Mark Allen Weiss's BST for BST implementation with AVL implementation for balancing.

Comment: Thank you! I just have trouble with syntax switching between C and Java.